# how to rsync git repos with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, rsync

I am trying to rsync git repo containing submodules from my development system to debug system. The command I am using is `rsync -vazrP /mydevelopmentFolder debug_pc:path`.

The problem is that after the rsync when I do a `git diff` I find the following error:

```
fatal: not a git repository: <abs path of my dev system>/<sub module path>
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule <submodule path>
```

The `git log` seems to work okay at the root level or at sub module level.
It is interesting to see that git repo contains the old absolute path to the subsystem (issue would not have been there is these were relative).

What am I doing wrong here? How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you doing an rsync instead of a clone ?

Comment: Perhaps you could specify the submodules as relative paths instead of full paths. I don't know if they will then be stored relative as well or not.

Comment: @Ôrel Clone is an alternative but i would like to make rsync work as that would save me some extra steps

Comment: @lucidbrot I dont really know how to do that. I am totally new to git submodule feature

Comment: rsync won't save you time imho. If you need to use git feature do a clone, if you just want the same code do an rsync without .git directory

Comment: @yashC I'm sure you'll find more info fairly quickly by googling for something like "git submodules relative path". I'm not on my laptop right now. As I said, not sure it'll help. But could be worth a try